# PHPStorm autocompletion for $this

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

My 'problem' is rather simple but I haven't been able to figure it out - is there a way to make PHPStorm offer "$this->" as an autocomplete option when I start typing "$th" instead of offering "$this" (without the arrow) ? Is there maybe some other solution to this which I don't know about?

Comment: Is typing the extra 2 chars really a problem?

Comment: No, it would just come in handy if it could automatically add them.

Comment: I would suggest creating a **Live Template**, that would replace `t[TAB]` by `$this->` -- even faster (IMO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the autocomplete feature because it does not know beforehand if youre typing '$this' as a function parameter, as a return variable or whatever situation you need it for. The autocomplete will loop the variables available in your current scope - and 'this' is allways within closure of a class function.

As LazyOne states, use a custom template instead, see:

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html